# Semantic Variability of Clause Chaining?

Tags: semantics, clauses

my question concerns languages with clause chaining - that form sentences composed of a string of non-finite medial clauses followed by a finite final clause, or a finite initial clause followed by a string of non-finite sequential clauses. Languages such as Turkish, Korean, etc.

What are typically the semantic constraints of clauses which may be chained together in this way? Is it typical for them to have to all take the same logical (though obviously not marked) aspect, mood, voice, etc.? Must there be a uniform semantic relation between them, such as a sequence of events where there is a "then" relation between clauses, or a conjunction where there is an "and" relation between them? How strict or loose are the constraints governing what clauses can come in a single chain and when a new chain must be started?

Comment: Specify the languages; each has invented its own system, and especially its own sets of idioms and familiar collocation frames. Description comes after data, and comparison comes after description. Unless you just want theoretical predications and predictions.

Comment: I suppose I am looking for theoretical predications and predictions. I'm wondering if there are any generalities that can be drawn.

Comment: Pick your presuppositions, make up your rules, and you can predict anything you like. There's tons of assumptions one can make, especially unfettered by data, and most of them are already made by somebody, and contradicted by somebody else, so it's up to you.

Comment: ...okay, let's try phrasing it this way: I'm looking for a survey/typology of clause chaining

Comment: Well, here's [a QD googling for "clause chaining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%22clause+chaining%22). One can do likewise for "serial verb", which is one of the more common names for the construction type; it has [a Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb). And, lucky for everybody, Arnold Zwicky has [a very good article](http://www.stanford.edu/~zwicky/serial-verbs.pdf) online on the subject.